# What is the formal mathematical model of a register machine?

Tags: computation-models, discrete-mathematics

I have been searching the web for a *mathematical model* of a register machine and have fallen short. The closest I have found is found [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/0910/CompTheory/comt-notes.pdf):

[image]

But I am looking for more detail than what is provided there, such as similar to the Turing Machine definition using tuples:

[image]

What resource describes the mathematical definition of either register machines or RAM machines at this level of formality? If none exist, how would you describe it (or please write the definition here otherwise for reference).

Answer (score 2):

In my taste the register machine definition you found is good to go. The only difference is that it specifies its components using the phrase "is specified by", whereas the second definition lists those components explicitly as a 7-tuple.

The components of the register machine in tuple style are probably a sequence of registers, a set of labels, and a list of instructions, one for each label. What is perhaps lacking is the specification of an initial label, where the computation starts.

Your Turing machine might be formally specified, but it contains only the hardware (states and alphabet) and the program (transition function) but it lacks semantics: how do we build computations, what is the behaviour of the machine?
The register machine does contains some semantics, although in words only, "add 1 to the contents of register $R$", but quite sufficient to see what is the meaning of the instructions.

Note there is no unique formalization of a register machine. There are variuos possibilities for the available instruction types. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Alternative_names,_alternative_models) lists various historical variants.